# Правильно ли подключены костыли на разные версии JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Правильно ли подключены костыли?

```
  <script src='js/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script>var $old_jq = jQuery.noConflict(true); </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>var $jq224 = jQuery.noConflict(true); </script>
        <script>

        (function($) {
             $.ajax({
              url: "js/all.js",
              dataType: "script",
              success: success
            });                    
            }($old_jq)); 

         (function($) {                      

              $(".tel").mask("+7(999) 999-9999");

            }($jq224));

         </script>
```

Comment: А ваш скрипт js/all.js (кстати, почему без кавычек?) знает про переменную $old_jq?

Comment: так все-таки - правильно или нет?

Comment: Зависит от того как оно используется в других скриптах.

Comment: В старой версии свалены скрипты под старую версию, в новую - под новые скрипты

Comment: Ну не желаете сообщать подробности - не сообщайте. Только не пойму зачем вы вопрос задавали в таком случае.

Comment: вам написать сюда 50 скриптов? Мне нужен ответ профессионала: в сути правильно ли подключаются скрипты?

Comment: Ответ профессионала: зависит от того, что ожидают другие ваши скрипты. Приведенный вами способ подключения может быть как правильным, так и неправильным.

Comment: какую информацию нужно предоставить для большего представления о проблеме?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного поправил твой скрипт, скачай код, сравни со своим, сохрани и запусти, как видишь у тебя подключаются 2 версии JQuery, которые доступны по двум разным переменным $old_jq и $jq224. Это сработает, добавил в примере вывод версий. 
Строку js/all.js надо добавить в ковычки, на будущее ставь try{}catch(){} для отлова ошибок.
А ещё не хватает плагина для маски телефона, добавил ссылку.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">var $old_jq = jQuery.noConflict(true)</script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">var $jq224 = jQuery.noConflict(true)</script>
</head>
<body>
    Скачай и установи плагин с маской отсюда: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask
    <hr/>
    <input id="tel" class="tel" type="text" style="width:100px" />
    <hr/>
    <span id="old_jq"></span><br/>
    <span id="jq224"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {
    try{
        $old_jq.ajax({
            url: js/all.js,
            dataType: "script",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        }); 
    } catch(e){ 
        console.log(e); 
    }   
})(); 

(function() {                      
    try{
        $jq224(".tel").mask("+7(999) 999-9999");
    } catch(e){ 
        console.log(e); 
    }
})($jq224);

console.log($old_jq.fn.jquery);
console.log($jq224.fn.jquery);

$old_jq("#old_jq").html('Для <b>$old_jq</b> версия JQuery: ' + $old_jq.fn.jquery);
$jq224("#jq224").html('Для <b>$jq224</b> версия JQuery: ' + $jq224.fn.jquery);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Прикольно и красиво. Когда уже я буду так писать! Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Для справки, о том зачем нужен $.noConflict() можно почитать здесь https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ .